# Como estilizar/customizar as cores das variaveis dentro do VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alguém sabe como faço parar estilizar/customizar as cores dentro do VSCODE?

Exemplo: Eu quero que as variáveis fiquem na cor preta..

Eu consegui achar o nome das classes, porem não sei como altera-las dentro do `settings.json`

Answer (score 3):

Vá no arquivo **`settings.json`**, para acessar ele vá em View > Command Pallete ou simplesmente pressione as teclas Ctrl+Shift+P (ou Cmd+Shift+P em MacOS), então no campo que aparece digite `settings.json` e selecione a primeira opção, deve aparecer algo como:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.fontSize": 22
}
```

Antes de tudo, existe a documentação aonde pode ver todas possibilidades: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors

Edite para isso:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.fontSize": 22,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#000"
    },
}
```

O `#000` é o mesmo que a cor preta, você pode alterar como desejar, por exemplo laranja: `"variables": "#fc0"`, você pode usar o "colorpick" nativo, ficará algo como:

[image: colorpick no VSCode]